# Why is the 'label' tag not working in ie8

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" style="display:none;" value="check1" id="ch1">
  <label for="ch1">check1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" style="display:none;" value="check2" id="ch2">
  <label for="ch2">check2</label>
</body>
</html>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
  function showValues() {
     alert(this.value);
  }
  $( "input[type='checkbox']" ).on( "click", showValues );
</script>
```

it work like below picture in ie10 when you click the "check1" text

[image]

but it not working in ie8

Comment: I am using IE 8 and it works.

Comment: What does “not working” mean here? No popup message? Clicking on the label does not toggle the checkbox?

Comment: There is no popup message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `<script>` tags inside the `<body>`.

I think you want to register your clicks on the labels instead of the checkboxes too (since you are not actually displaying the checkboxes).  Try this:

```
function showValues() {
   alert($("#"+$(this).attr("for")).val());
}
$("label").on("click", showValues);
```

Comment: thanks for you answer.But it not works for me.do you have a test?make sure you test it in IE8.

Comment: @一无所有 I think I see the other issue. You're event is firing on click of the checkboxes, which you aren't displaying. I updated my answer with the additional change you'll need to make and tested it on IE8 to confirm it works.

Comment: Your answer is working.But it isn't my wanted.I want to know why the same code show different result between IE8 and IE10.I want know why it is success in IE10 and fail in IE8

Comment: I'm not a Microsoft engineer so I would only be speculating if I tried to answer that question. IE is notorious for having fairly major inconsistencies in rendering HTML/CSS and interpreting JavaScript. You have probably just discovered one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  function showValues() {
     alert(this.value);
  }
  $( "input[type='checkbox']" ).on( "click", showValues );
});
</script>


</head>
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" style="display:none;" value="check1" id="ch1">
  <label for="ch1">check1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" style="display:none;" value="check2" id="ch2">
  <label for="ch2">check2</label>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Where is **$(document).ready();**

Answer (score 0):

```
there are several items within the code 
that result in 'browser guesses' as to what you actually want.
Like having both check boxes having the same name 
they are NOT radio buttons so the names should be unique
A input attribute ID="..." is for CSS definitions, not for input identification

<input type="checkbox" name="check" style="display:none;" value="check1" id="ch1">
<label for="ch1">check1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" style="display:none;" value="check2" id="ch2">
<label for="ch2">check2</label>

To greatly help the browser, the code should look more like:

<label>
    check1
    <input type="checkbox" name="check1" style="display:none;" value="check1" />
</label>
<label>
    check2
    <input type="checkbox" name="check2" style="display:none;" value="check2" />
</label>
```

Comment: thanks for you answer.But it not works for me.do you have a test?make sure you test it in IE8